# Scrollbar shows up in a reverse/opposite direction

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, telerik

I have a WPF application.
I use telerik and in one of the panes I have a WindowsFormsHost to host a winforms. 
My problem: whenever I resize the pane in a way that a horizontal scroller becomes visibile, the scroller is behaving in a wierd way: if the scroller is all the way to the right then the winforms/WindowsFormsHost that is displayed is all the way to the left and vise versa.
I have tried playing with snoop, changing the FlowDirection but it doesn't help (and the FlowDirection is always LeftToRight).
Any ideas?

This is the relevent part of the code:

```
<telerik:RadDocking PanesSource="{Binding Items}" telerik:RadDocking.SerializationTag="itemDocking" x:Name="itemDocking" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="
    <telerik:RadDocking.DocumentHost>
        <telerik:RadSplitContainer BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0">
            <telerik:RadPaneGroup  BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0">
                <telerik:RadDocumentPane BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" telerik:RadDocking.SerializationTag="MainItemHost"  IsHidden="False" Visibility="Collapsed" CanUserClose="False">
                        <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="itemFormsHost">

                        </WindowsFormsHost>
                </telerik:RadDocumentPane>
            </telerik:RadPaneGroup>
        </telerik:RadSplitContainer>
    </telerik:RadDocking.DocumentHost>
```

Comment: do you mean that as you move your scroll to the right the data on the screen goes left?

Comment: Yes, that's my problem

Comment: but thats exactly what it should do, as you scroll to the right, you are moving to view things on the right hand side, so things will move left ways to make room

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand you, when the scroll is maxed to the right I see the end of the form from the left side. It has an opposite behavior than for example a scrollbar on Google Chrome

Comment: if you had a button in the middle of the screen, as the scrollbar position is moved to the right, the button heads left...  Normally you have to go out of your way to get the reverse to happen.. as its not normal for windows

Comment: Ok I understand now what you mean, so my problem is that if I have a button in the middle and I move the scroll bar to the right than the button heads right as well. I tried snooping and changing the default values and than tried google, but so far nothing has worked

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139263/flip-scrollbar-wpf  the problem is it normally wouldnt do this without specific coding to make it do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After BugFinder's comment I started looking in the whole solution for that code in the xaml/xaml.cs.
When I couldn't find anything I understood that it must be in the Winforms.
Apparently one of the items in the form (which is a tree control) had a:

```
tree.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;
```

Which caused the scroll to act that way (even though the whole tree display was Left to Right). 
I understood that the bug was in the tree when I noticed that when I move the scroll it only effects the tree (which takes the whole length) and the toolbar in the form.

Hope this helps someone and thank you BugFinder for guiding me to the solution.