# Compiler error when creating IntegerUpDown ValueChanged event

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using the `IntegerUpDown` control from [WPFExtendedToolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=IntegerUpDown#properties_events)

However, I'm unable to assign the event my function so that when the value is changed it will call my function.  I'm pretty new to both c# and wpf so help is greatly appreciated.  I've been trying to get it to work as show in a similar example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841293/where-is-the-wpf-numeric-updown-control).

```
private IntegerUpDown m_argumentUpDown;

public IntArgumentOption(ArgumentOptionDescription argumentDesc) : base(argumentDesc)
{
    m_argumentUpDown = new IntegerUpDown
    {
        Watermark = argumentDesc.m_watermark,
        Increment = (int)argumentDesc.m_interval,
        Minimum = (int)argumentDesc.m_minimum,
        Maximum = (int)argumentDesc.m_maximum,
        FormatString = "G",
        SelectAllOnGotFocus = true,
        MinWidth = 50,
        FontSize = 10,
        Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness(5, 0, 0, 0),
    };

    // COMPILER ERROR:
    m_argumentUpDown.ValueChanged += new RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<int>(ArgumentChanged);
}

void ArgumentChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<int> e)
{

}
```

Doing this results in the compiler error:

> error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler< int >' to 'System.Windows.RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler< object >'

Comment: Did you tried to use it explicitly? like `(System.Windows.RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler)error_variable`

Comment: If you mean new System.Windows.RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<int>(ArgumentChanged) ?  that doesn't work either

Comment: Have you tried using a nullable type? ie: RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<int?>

Comment: That wont work either. it just changes the error output to int? instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here in the UpDownBase class (Xceed.wpfToolkit.dll) the method signature for ValueChanged is:

```
public event RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<object> ValueChanged;
```

hence in your code you have to declare a event handler where the generic is of type "**Object**" instead of **int**. Because of the mismatch in type the compiler is unable to implicitly convert to Int from object. 
So change code as below

```
m_argumentUpDown.ValueChanged += new RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<object>(ArgumentChanged);

    }

    void ArgumentChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {
           //type caste e.newValue and e.OldValue 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will work, I tested that. But I dont know if this is considered work around or creator of IntegerUpDown control meant it to be used this way.

```
m_argumentUpDown.ValueChanged += new RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<object>(ArgumentChanged);
//or you can change above line to following for brevity. ReSharper always suggesting me to do this
//m_argumentUpDown.ValueChanged += ArgumentChanged;

void ArgumentChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{
    //you need to cast New and Old value to int since both are of type object now
    int newVal = (int)e.NewValue;
    int oldVal = (int)e.OldValue;
}
```