# Can i make UpDown Column at DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid, numericupdown

Can i make UpDown Column at DataGrid?

I have simple DataGrid:

```
 <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name">  </DataGridTextColumn>

                            </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>
```

And i want to make UpDown column. Can i do that?

Thank you!

P.S. i mean something like numericUpDown counter. :up: [1], down: [0].

Comment: whats an updown column ?

Comment: i mean something like numericUpDown counter. :up: [1], down: [0].

Comment: Yea guessed that, have a look at posted answer.
Use wpfToolkit, that one is fairly simple to use.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do something like

```
<DataGrid>
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=AttrName}" Height="25" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=AttrDisplayLabel}" Height="25" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox Height="25" 
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsAttributes}}"
                                      SelectedValuePath="AttributeID"
                                      IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"
                                      SelectionChanged="Selector_OnSelectionChanged"
                                      SelectedValue="{Binding Path=AttributeId, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">

                                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>

                                <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <VirtualizingStackPanel />
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>

                            </ComboBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
 ....
```

Just replace combo with your updown/spinner control. The celltemplate is your display... the celledittemplate is your edit control...(updown...etc...)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean NumericUpDown column

you can have a template column and add NumericUpDown Control to the template

Look [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841293/where-is-the-wpf-numeric-updown-control) for creating custom numeric updown control or simply use one provided with WPFToolkit !!

Find Codeples for Toolkit [Here](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=NumericUpDown)