# How to create Numeric UpDown in UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10, uwp-xaml

I am creating a derived class of TextBox for numeric data entry. I would like to add 2 buttons at the right side, like the X button in some TextBox controls to increment or decrement the value.

How can I do it?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Of course. I am trying to create a derived class, a custom control with all these features. I can find information about WPF but I am looking for UWP and after hours googling, I have found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a Numeric Updown. See this question for how to implement your own

[Where is the WPF Numeric UpDown control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841293/where-is-the-wpf-numeric-updown-control)

Comment: Thank you. I am using the "ControlTemplate" response. The first one, adding controls in the page is not a reusable solution. The code is for WPF but with some changes, it works fine for UWP.