# NumericUpDown is not supported in a WPF project

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to add a [NumericUpDown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown(v=vs.110).aspx) to my WPF window at design time in Visual Studio 2013.
So far I simply have:

```
<NumericUpDown/>
```

Which gives me the Error: `NumericUpDown is not supported in a Window Presentatio Foundation (WPF) project.`

I think I'm misunderstanding something about namespaces in XAML, I've tried to add the full namespace but that still gets the same error. All the help I see online is older and is about building your own.

Comment: Show some clear code, how you try to add the control. The namespace and how you adding it etc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is the WPF Numeric UpDown control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841293/where-is-the-wpf-numeric-updown-control)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not directly use Winforms control(based on link in your question to NumericUpDown) in WPF. To do that you need to use [WindowsFormsHost](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost(v=vs.100).aspx) control and inside this use the WinForm controls

So to get the `NumericUpDown` in wpf you need to do below steps:

Add a reference to your WPF project to `System.Windows.Forms` and import in case of XAML like:

```
xmlns:winforms="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"
```

Render the control:

```
<StackPanel>
   <WindowsFormsHost>
       <winforms:NumericUpDown />
   </WindowsFormsHost>
</StackPanel>
```

You can learn more on this from MSDN for [XAML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms742875(v=vs.100).aspx) and [Code Behind (C#/VB)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms751761(v=vs.100).aspx)

Hope this give you some idea to start with, if this is the route you want to do it.

Answer (score 3):

By default, there is no NumericUpDown control.

There is, however, a NumericUpDown-like control included in the [wpftoolkit](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit).
It's called IntegerUpDown. There is also a DecimalUpDown and a DoubleUpDown.

Edit: Updated link since Codeplex has been down for some time now.