# ListBox as Numeric UpDown control in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listbox

One of the disadventage I found in WPF is it doesnot have a Numeric UpDown control.
So I make a listbox with height as 25 so that it will display only one item at a time and the vertical scroll feels like a UpDown controls. 
My problem is when I use the scroll to change the value, I can't get the current value shown in listbox. Can any idea to get the value shown in listbox without selecting it?

Comment: There's a similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/382676/good-numericupdown-equivalent-in-wpf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though there's no standard WPF NumericUpDown, you can try [NumericUpDown Custom Control with Theme and UI Automation Support Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771573.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

The Extented WPF Toolkit has one: [NumericUpDown](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=NumericUpDown&referringTitle=Home)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

well since you are using WPF, you can change the template of your ListBoxItem and change it's look to nothing when the item is selected ( i mean remove the trigger ), that's all.
I hope it's helpful, unless you need other things than this.

Answer (score 1):

You can also attach a ScrollBar.Scroll event. This fires when you scroll. Maybe you can then change the SelectedIndex manually or set the focus?