# Is there a Up/Down Combo button in WPF control?

Tags: c#, wpf, button

In my WPF C# application, I want to add a Up / Down (or Plus / Minus) button to increment or decrement an integer in a TextBox. Is there such a control or do I need to write and position a TextBox and two Buttons?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/841293/where-is-the-wpf-numeric-updown-control

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good NumericUpDown equivalent in WPF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/382676/good-numericupdown-equivalent-in-wpf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft has a "[NumericUpDown Custom Control with Theme and UI Automation Support Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771573.aspx)"

Other useful links:

- http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=NumericUpDown&referringTitle=Home
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/NumericUpDownTextBox.aspx
- http://code.google.com/p/phoenix-control-library/