# Using Vscrollbar in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to disable the textbox control and control the numeric input to the text box control using vertical scroll bar. How can I do that?

Comment: You may need to be a bit more descriptive. Are you asking how to add a numeric masked text box field where you can set the value of the field using up/down arrows next to the box? (See this sample towards the middle of the page: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/input/examples/radnumerictextbox/firstlook/defaultcs.aspx )

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't sound like `TextBox` is the right control to be using; seems like you want something more like this:
[image]

If you're using Windows Forms, you can use the [`NumericUpDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.aspx) control.

If you're using WPF, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/382676/good-numericupdown-equivalent-in-wpf) has several options listed.