# Restricting a WPF Textbox to integers by swallowing an exception

Tags: c#, wpf

I've written the following to restrict a WPF textbox to only accept integers and also only accept a number less than or equal to 35:

In my WindowLoaded event I create a handler for 'OnPaste':

```
DataObject.AddPastingHandler(textBoxWorkflowCount, OnPaste);
```

OnPaste consists of the following:

```
private void OnPaste(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsNumeric(e.Source.ToString(), NumberStyles.Integer)) e.Handled = true;
}
```

and our function to force numerics only is as follows:

```
public bool IsNumeric(string val, NumberStyles numberStyle)
{
    double result;
    return double.TryParse(val, numberStyle, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out result);
}
```

The specific textbox that is having the error should also be limited to a number <=35. To do this I've added the following TextChanged event:

```
private void TextBoxWorkflowCountTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (textBoxWorkflowCount == null || textBoxWorkflowCount.Text == string.Empty || Convert.ToInt32(textBoxWorkflowCount.Text) <= 35) return;
                MessageBox.Show("Number of workflow errors on one submission cannot be greater then 35.", "Workflow Count too high", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
                textBoxWorkflowCount.Text = "";
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {
                // todo: Oh the horror! SPAGHETTI! Must fix. Temporarily here to stop 'pasting of varchar' bug
                if (textBoxWorkflowCount != null) textBoxWorkflowCount.Text = "";
            }

        }
```

Although this does the job and works it's very nasty/hackish and I would love to know how it could be done better for sake of improving myself... Especially so without having to swallow an exception.

Comment: Have you considered using MVVM with databinding?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/382676/good-numericupdown-equivalent-in-wpf

Comment: @ChrisShain Doesn't seem relevant to my case? Could you explain how you see the two as being related, I'm missing it?

Comment: @codesparkle I do - but wasn't sure if this was a better home for it? Is it better if I move it over there?

Comment: I reckon it would fit there really well. If the moderators agree, they will migrate it, you needn't take any action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you? Replace the content of `TextBoxWorkflowCountTextChanged` with this:

```
if (textBoxWorkflowCount == null || textBoxWorkflowCount.Text == string.Empty) return;
int workflowcount = 36;
if (int.TryParse(textBoxWorkflowCount.Text, out workflowcount) && workflowcount > 35) {
    MessageBox.Show("Number of workflow errors on one submission cannot be greater then 35.", "Workflow Count too high", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
    textBoxWorkflowCount.Text = "";
}
else if (workflowcount == 36) {
    textBoxWorkflowCount.Text = "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on of QtotheC's, answer I arrived at the following after a bit more refactoring. Adding here for future visitors :)

```
    private void TextBoxWorkflowCountTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxWorkflowCount.Text))
            return;

        int workflowCount;

        if (!int.TryParse(textBoxWorkflowCount.Text, out workflowCount) || workflowCount <= 35) return;
        MessageBox.Show("Number of workflow errors on one submission cannot be greater then 35.", "Workflow Count too high",
                        MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
        textBoxWorkflowCount.Text = "35";
    }
```

Comment: you *could* combine the two conditions with || (that would reduce nesting).

Comment: @codesparkle Don't you mean && for the second if statement? Will edit / update with thatn ow.

Comment: It's ok, just to be cheeky I inverted so I could use || :)

Comment: You'd have a `NullPointerException` at `string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxWorkflowCount.Text)` if `textBoxWorkflowCount` is ever null. Not that it will matter much--this event should never fire if the textbox is null.