# StringUpDown in WPF?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, scrollbar, wpftoolkit, numericupdown

I have a question regarding the following question about NumericUpDown:

[Good NumericUpDown equivalent in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/382676/good-numericupdown-equivalent-in-wpf)

How I can do this for 12 months of a year? I am planning to use a vertical ScrollBar with a textbox. I want to link the vertical ScrollBar up and down clicks to increment and decrement the months in the textbox using C#.

```
<ScrollBar x:Name="scbm" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="230,195,0,0" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.542,0.83"/>

<TextBox x:Name="txtm" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="139,195,0,0" 
    TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="66"/>
```

Can anyone tell me how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Since you have found an answer to your question here, please delete your other question - [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19829031/good-stringupdown-equivalent-in-wpf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19829031/good-stringupdown-equivalent-in-wpf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/663143/Quick-intro-to-DatePicker-tricks-and-MVVM-thoughts) article that does something similar with a datepicker.

Basically you'll want to have a property for the month, and depending on your approach (code behind / mvvm), handle the click events on the up/down buttons, or the keyboard keydown event to handle them logic  (so in your case, add the up/down buttons, and wire them to the events, naming them appropriately).

For example, having this on your xaml:

```
<DatePicker ... PreviewKeyDown="PreviewKeyDown_EventHandler" ...  />
```

And something like this in your code behind:

```
private void PreviewKeyDown_EventHandler(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
  // Avoid them nasty exceptions is the user hits "up" or "down" with no date selected:
  if (sender == null || ((DatePicker)sender).SelectedDate == null)
    return;

  // Do this on up 
  if (e.Key == Key.Up)
  {
     ((DatePicker)sender).SelectedDate =
    ((DatePicker)sender).SelectedDate.GetValueOrDefault().AddMonths(1);
  }

  // And this on down
  if (e.Key == Key.Down)
  {
    ((DatePicker)sender).SelectedDate =
    ((DatePicker)sender).SelectedDate.GetValueOrDefault().AddMonths(-1);
  }
}
```

That example uses a datetime as the property, but you can do similar things with an int if that's what you're after.

(again, have a look at the link for more options, examples, and code example if you'd like)

---

**Edit:**

This doesn't have theh benefits of the up/down keys like the article's example, but this works:

```
<ScrollBar x:Name="scbm" 
    SmallChange="1" Maximum="12" Minimum="1"

    Value="{Binding MonthScrollBar}"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="230,195,0,0" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.542,0.83" />

<TextBox x:Name="txtm" 
    Text="{Binding MonthScrollBar}"

    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="139,195,0,0" 
    TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="66" />
```

On my ViewModel (or your codebehind, if you want, do something similar)

```
public int MonthScrollBar
{
    get { return _monthScrollBar; }
    set { _monthScrollBar = value; 
          RaisePropertyChanged("MonthScrollBar");}
}
private int _monthScrollBar;
```

And setting the property value to whatever you want on the constructor.

Note that I'm using MVVM, binding to a property with notification change (so changes are propagating to the View), and initializing it. 
Both the ScrollBar and TextBox bind to the same `MonthScrollBar` property)
If you're doing code behind, you can access it directly from the code behind.

Comment: I need only months just like this link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html

Comment: If you're binding to a DateTime, add or subtract a month. If you're binding to a number, add or substract 1 from the property. You've got all the info you need right there ...

Comment: Datepicker is showing complete date :mm/dd/yyyy  ..But i want to display string of month to user.

Comment: Obviously, It's from the given example. You can either have a `TextBox` , or play with the date format. (I'll suggest you use a textbox, and have an int there, just make sure in your logic to go from 12 to 1 when you hit up)

Comment: Do you mean use text box along with ScrollBar ????my question is how to link the ScrollBar up and down clicks to increment and decrement the months in the textbox?

Comment: note: where did I suggest to use any framework? I suggest you look up MVVM [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) or [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx), and in the meanwhile, work with your codebehind