# Where can i get the xctk:DecimalUpDown xaml so that i can Customize the way i want it?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xceed, material-design-in-xaml

In my WPF C# project i wanted to use the DecimalUpDown control but it doesn't have the same feel and look as my other controls in the UserControl because i am Using MaterialDesignThemes in MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit.
Now what i wanted is to Customize the TextBox part of the DecimalUpDown of the ExtendedWPFToolkit and the Button Part so that they look like materialDesignFloatingHintTextBox and one of the MaterialDesignButton styles respectively.
I tried that but can't find anywhere to start like the Source Code etc

Comment: I suggest creating a custom DecimalUpDown control by developing a UserControl containing a text block and two buttons. These buttons can be styled using Material Design. Then, you can use the UserControl as a UI element.

Comment: i found some like  this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/382676/good-numericupdown-equivalent-in-wpf and another here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841293/where-is-the-wpf-numeric-updown-control/63734191#63734191 but the question is, Will I get all the functionalities like in DecimalUpDown, if yes let me know it.

Comment: yes you can add code behind for each button if you are using mvvm i already added an example in my answer

Comment: OK, currently i am not using mvvm, and i don't like code-behind, because i have alot of codes there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried that but can't find anywhere to start like the Source Code etc

The source code for the `DecimalUpDown` control is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/blob/4b23a638b1a41589e3d4dfa1c226336c00a18134/ExtendedWPFToolkitSolution/Src/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit/NumericUpDown/Implementation/DecimalUpDown.cs#L22).

Here you will also find the [default template](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/blob/4b23a638b1a41589e3d4dfa1c226336c00a18134/ExtendedWPFToolkitSolution/Src/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit/NumericUpDown/Themes/Generic.xaml#L142) that you can customize however you want.

Answer (score 0):

try using userControle as UI Element

```
<UserControl x:Class="namespace.Views.MyUpAndDown"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:namespace.Views"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
                xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"

         d:DesignHeight="80" d:DesignWidth="200">
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Background="{StaticResource MaterialDesignCardBackground}" MinWidth="140" Text="{Binding Value}"/>
    <StackPanel Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Vertical">
        <Button Margin="1" Command="{Binding Increment}">
            <Button.Content>
                <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="ArrowTop"/>
            </Button.Content>
        </Button>
        <Button Margin="1" Command="{Binding Descrement}">
            <Button.Content>
                <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="ArrowDown"/>
            </Button.Content>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

[image: you can apply the material design styling in the user controle]

Comment: i think creating a customControl to function like DecimalUpDown, you have to alot to code, don't forgetting bugs

Comment: the material design themes doesn't cover all standards ui so if it is necessary to   you to have the same feel and look you have to design your own

Comment: OK, thanks @Ahmed Laoun that's why in this Question I am looking for somebody to guide me where i can get the Source Code of xctk:DecimalUpDown so that i can customize it so as to avoid bugs and do simple work. I think know you have understood why i have asked this question ("Where can i get the xctk:DecimalUpDown xaml so that i can Customize the way i want it?"). Thanks.